# Changing the values in a <select> using another <select> using AJAX (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to change the values of a select using another select

As you can see both selects are filled using PHP.

Now what I wanted was that when choosing a certain specialty, the select containing the medics would change.

Here's the code

```
            <select id="specialties" class = "formulario_text">
                <?php foreach ($specialties as $especialidade_id => $especialidade) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $especialidade_id; ?>"><?php echo $especialidade; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>
                <b class="formulario_labels2">Médico:*</b>
            </label>
            <br>
            <select id="medics" class="formulario_text">
                <?php foreach ($medics as $id => $nome) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $nome; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

I have little knowledge on AJAX, PHP and Javascript, so I'm pretty much hitting a wall here. Was hoping anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

So far I have this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#specialties").change(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "16") {
                $("#medics").html("<option value='1'> <?php $medics[1]; ?> </option>");
            } 
        });

    });
```

I was testing to see if I could capture the first position of the $medics array that I have in another file.

$specialties = model\ClinicalSpecialty::getSpecialties();

$medics = model\Medic::getMedics();

And the methods work like this

```
static function getSpecialties(){

    $res = array();
    $db = new DBAccess();

    if($db->conn){
        $query = 'select id,name from clinical_specialty';
        $result_set = $db->conn->query($query);
        while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
            $res[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
        }
        $result_set->free();
        $db->conn->close();
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Sorry for not adding this code at first

Comment: Where is JavaScript, JQuery or Ajax code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried this as a test
            $("#specialties").change(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val == "16") {
                    $("#medics").html("<option value='1'> <?php $medics[1]; ?> </option>");
                } 
            });

Comment: I've tried nothing with AJAX, since I'm having some issues understanding it

Comment: I have edited my answer to your edit. Please check if i'm close to what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best off dividing this in steps, which is (I think) the easiest way to understand it.

I do not know for sure how to include this with your PHP, as I don't know anything about the rest of your code. I will give you a static example and you will have to combine it with the PHP yourself. I hope it'll help anyways!

**Step 1: include jquery.**

You have to include the jQuery library between your html `<head>` tags like so:
(if you already have jQuery included, skip this step)

```
<!--including jQuery here -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

**step 2:working in javascript.** 
You first have to fire an onload callback so your functions know when to go off, like so:

```
<script>
//When page is done loading
$(document).ready(function(){
});
</script>
```

**step 3: the big script**

```
//When page is done loading
$(document).ready(function() {
// let's get your select first!
    var firstSelector = $('#yourSelectID');
    var medicSelector = $('#yourMedicSelectID');
    //we will fill this variable on select changes
    var currentSelection = firstSelector.val();
    //set initial medic values
    medicSelector.html(
    "your options here as strings (between the quotes). see below for example"

);


    //get value on change
    firstSelector.change(function() {
        currentSelection = $(this).val();

        //check if the current value is what you want
        if (currentSelection == "1") {
            //This replaces the options completely
            medicSelector.html(
                    //you can use any PHP variable here to fill it. 
                    //Just use <?php echo $optionsforthischoice ?>
                    // $optionsforthischoice would be filled like so:
                    //  $optionsforthischoice = "<option>option1</option><option>option2</option> etc.;
                    "<option>option1</option><option>option2</option><option>option3</option>"
                    );
        }
        if (currentSelection == "2") {
            // do the same here as for 1, but when 2 is selected!
        }

    });
});
```

Important note:
This style is quite static, as you can see. If you want a more dynamic solution you are going to give us better info and more code.

This Javascript replaces the options you had previously, so you have to rewrite them for every if statement. They do not add or substract. They completely replace.

**!EDIT!**

I see you have edited your question. Now I can properly help. I will leave the above "tutorial" for reference.  (By the way, you can use a php foreach loop te get the full array into your javascript as well)

**see below**

If you want to do this properly, you might want to connect the dots in the database, and use sql joins instead. It would save you a lot of code and make the whole thing easier. However, since you probably haven't, there is only one proper way to solve this.
You see, you cannot use ajax on a specific function. You will have to make a php script.

You will make for example "getMedics.php".

Then you will call the "getMedics.php" file with an ajax call when the selection changes, like so:

```
//The first option is the link to the file
//The ?specialty is a parameter which you are going to get in the script.
//This will be the selection that was made before
//Within the function "result" will be the variable with the values the phpscript returns
$.get('phpscripts/getMedics.php?specialty=' + $("#specialties").val(), function(result) {
//if the result returned anything
    if (result.trim()) {
        //you will want the result to be the options
        $('#medics').html(result);
    }
});
```

Now the php script will be trickier. This is about how it's going to look:

```
//get the specialty ID
$specialty = strip_tags($_GET['specialty']);
//get the medics
//i'm guessing the results will be arrays within arrays
$medics = Medic::getMedics();
//set the array for the options
$options = array();
//prepare our results
$optionResults = "";

switch ($specialty) {
    case 0:
        $options[1] = "1";
        $options[2] = "2";
        $options[3] = "5";
        $options[4] = "7";
        break;
    case 1:
        $options[1] = "1";
        $options[2] = "2";
        $options[3] = "5";
        $options[4] = "7";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "specialty equals 2";
        break;
}

//this foreach loop will pass the options to a variable
foreach($option as $options){
    //.= adds to the variable
    $optionResults .= "<option value='".$medics[$option][0]."'>".$medics[$option][1]."</option>";
}

//this is what will return as the ajaxed results:

echo $optionResults;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no code to show what you've tried, I'll try helping you from scratch. This will probably be similar to your solution:

```
$("#firstSelect").change(function(){
    $.post(
        "url/to/get/ajax/from",
        {dataToSend: $("this").val()},
        function(data){$("#selectToChange").val(data)}
    );
)};
```

syntax or something might be off but this may set you in the right direction at least.
ps include jquery