# Display different search options based on "search by" option in PHP

Tags: php

There are two drop down box which are search by (Division or Name) and search option selection box. So I want to change selection option based on input value of search by dropdown. According to my code all name and division search options are doesn't separate.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:auto>
    <div class="form-group"><?php
    <select name='by_type' value='' id='form-field-select-3' class='form-control search-select' data-placeholder='By' required><option></option>
           <option value="division">Division</option>
           <option value="name">Name</option>
     </select>
     </td><td></td>
     <td style="width:auto>
     <div class="form-group"><?php
            $query1 = "SELECT emp_id, name FROM employee WHERE user_status='active' ORDER BY name ASC";
            $result1 = mysql_query ($query1);
            echo "<select name='emp_id' value='' id='form-field-select-3' class='form-control search-select' data-placeholder='Search Here' required>   <option></option>";
            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo "<option value=".$r['emp_id'].">".$r['name']."</option>";
                                    }?>
                  <option value="Software Division">Software Division</option>
                  <option value="Financial Division">Financial Division</option>
                  <option value="Technical Division">Technical Division</option>
                  <option value="Research Division">Research Division</option>
                  <option value="Operation Division">Operation Division</option>
             </td>
             <td style="width:auto"><br>
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-purple" value="Search" name="click" style="height: 30px">
             </td></tr></div></table>
```

---

Please help me !

Comment: so, what is error?

Comment: There isn't any error, but I want to show search option based on search by option. For an example if user select division, another select option drop down should have to show only division's names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the values in a <select> using another <select> using AJAX (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274259/changing-the-values-in-a-select-using-another-select-using-ajax-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ajax for doing it. At first, display division drop down & use a js method with onchange event & call ajax method using that drop down option value. Then display that data on success to second drop down.

Like this -

```
<select name='by_type' value='' id='form-field-select-3' class='form-control search-select' data-placeholder='By' required onchange="select_division();"><option></option>
       <option value="division">Division</option>
       <option value="name">Name</option>
 </select>
```

Then call ajax method like this -

```
<script>
function select_division(){
 $.ajax({

 });
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: check above answer, hope you can do it now.

Comment: Can I put hidden submit field inside the select option tag instead of using ajax?

Comment: I have no idea about hidden submit field & I think, it's better approach. It's a very easy process.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with ajax JQuery.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "data.php",//file wich has query select to db table
            data: {search:searching},//describe your data here
            dataType: 'json',// type of data that will you get (JSON/HTML).
            type: 'POST',//sending type (POST/GET)
            success: function(data) {
               //do change the select option
            }
        });
```